# Retrofit Error :500 Internal server error in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, jwt

Am Using retrofit for my connection with server,My app has signin page and signout page During Login i get the value from text box and send using POST request to the server It works fine,

```
   public void LoginUser(View v)

{RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()      
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build(); 

    WashAPI api = adapter.create(WashAPI.class);

    api.LoginUser(



            Email.getText().toString(),
            Password.getText().toString(),

            //Creating an anonymous callback
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                    //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                    //Creating a bufferedreader object
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    try {
                        //Initializing buffered reader
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Interface for signin

```
public interface WashAPI {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/xxx/yyy/signin")
public void LoginUser(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,

        Callback<Response> callback);

}
```

This works good

After login with my server API it returns me a token, At the time of signout i need to send the token so my session get experied.

code for signout

```
public void signout(View v)
{
    Log.d("insidetoken",t);
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();
    SignoutAPI api = adapter.create(SignoutAPI.class);
             api.signout(t,
                    new Callback<Response>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Response result, Response response) {

                            BufferedReader reader = null;
                            String output = "";
                            try {
                                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                                output = reader.readLine();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Interface for signout

```
public interface SignoutAPI {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/xxx/yyy/zzz/signout")
public void signout(
       @Field("token") String token,
        Callback<Response> callback);
```

}

My code is same for both signin and sigout

but for signin it works and for signout it gives me RETROFIT ERROR : 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

But Using POSTMAN It works fine[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why Internal server error occurs during my signout operation???

Comment: Because there is an error on the server

Comment: But it works good in POSTMAN for the same signout

Comment: So? The error is still there. I suggest you check the server logs

Comment: In Postman, why are you sending parameters as query parameters ?

Comment: Yes, @Eric B i use the same way for signin page aslo it works fine..

Comment: This is definitely a server issue, something you are doing in the login service and not doing in the logout one.

Comment: Thanx @Eric i just checkd the complete log it gives me 

JWTException in JWTAuth.php line 295: A token is required---

token i send is not received by server so the server prompts me " token is required"

Comment: Great, i am posting my comment as answer.

Comment: I send the sameway for email and password for signin it works but for signout it doesnt work means that there is an error in android right

Answer (score 1):

**500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR** means that there is problem in the server side you should have to check it using postman.

I am damn sure that there will be problem in the web service response not of your code at android side.

Comment: The problem in SERVER is, It requires TOKEN but there is no token

JWTException in JWTAuth.php line 295: A token is required

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments too, it appears you are doing something in the login service that is not being done in the sign out service.

To fix this, make sure in you sign out service, you are checking for a POST parameter named `token`.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100634/get-the-post-request-body-from-httpservletrequest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are giving token in wrong way
In my way It was **"Bearer TOKEN"** -> for Authorization in Header
In my case I changed my parameters to that

```
fun setProfileAvatar(token: String,@Part image: MultipartBody.Part) : Single<Message> {
        return apiService.setProfileAvatar("Bearer ${token}",image)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging in retrofit to show you server-side errors and messages.
use this link to understand how to enable it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/9474700