# Why I am getting null value while parsing json object in servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, postman

My Json Object from postman:

```
{
    "sender":"hello"
}
```

My servlet `dopost` method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
     throws ServletException, IOException {

    Gson gs = new Gson();
    String chatId = gs.fromJson(req.getParameter("sender"), String.class);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 

    JSONArray arr= new JSONArray();
    try {
        obj.put("name", chatId);
        arr.add(obj);
    }       
    finally {
    }
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    resp.getWriter().println(arr);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your chatId non-null? Could you please check it out first?

Comment: `req.getParameter("sender")` attempts to read a sender HTTP parameter, not a JSON "sender" entry in the JSON object in the body of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong was not using Gson properly.

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new Gson().fromJson( new JsonReader(request.getReader()), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
```

This code directly converted my `Json` body into a `Hashmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I think JSON will come in request body. Refer [Get the POST request body from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100634/get-the-post-request-body-from-httpservletrequest) to read the requestbody from HttpServletRequest.