# Java mutlipart/formdata in `hash format` querying

Tags: servlets, multipartform-data

Ruby, PHP, Node, .NET, all can consume mutipart/formdata's hash format, e.g. (name => value):

```
user[name] => foo
user[id] => 10
user[account][id] = 10
user[account][status] = true
user[array][0] = 1
user[array][1] = 2
```

for example in Rails I'd query it like:

```
params[:user] #=> Hash {name: foo, id: 10}
params[:user][:name] #=> will return 10
params[:user][:array] #=> will return [1,2]
```

Is same achievable in Java (or maybe there's a library for this)?

EDIT:
To explain what I mean by the hash format:
[link](http://docs.cloudmailin.com/http_post_formats/multipart/#envelope)

Comment: Could you please explain, or provide any reason, why you need to send hash in form request?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I can't understand your question clearly, but from my opinion:

You should get request body as string, as described here:

[Get the POST request body from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100634/get-the-post-request-body-from-httpservletrequest)

And then call for md5 or similar function with request string - http://devcolibri.com/4604