# How to log all the request-responses in spring rest?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, logging

The application should log the following information without impacting a client, asynchronously(in a separate thread).

- Request HTTP Method and URI
- Request Headers (Except the default)
- Client's IP Address
- Request Processing Time(In milliseconds)
- Request Body
- Response Body

If we consume `inputstream` in the filter, then it cant be consumed again by spring for json to object mapping. Somewhere during the input stream to object mapping, can we plug our logger?

**Update:**

We can write over logging code in a [MessageConverter](https://gist.github.com/TheNilesh/9c7f3ab13ab0511c144e33e63672b08c), but it doesnt seems to be a good idea.

```
public class MyMappingJackson2MessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {
    ...
    protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        InputStream inputStream = inputMessage.getBody();
        String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String method = request.getMethod();
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        LOGGER.debug("{} {}", method, uri);
        LOGGER.debug("{}", requestBody);
        return objectMapper.readValue(requestBody, clazz);
    }

    protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        String responseBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        LOGGER.debug("{}", responseBody);
        outputMessage.getBody().write(responseBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An answer from [baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) :

> Spring provides a built-in solution to log payloads. We can use
>   ready-made filters by plugging into Spring application using
>   configuration. [AbstractRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html) is a filter which
>   provides basic functions of logging. Subclasses should override the
>   `beforeRequest()` and `afterRequest()` methods to perform the actual
>   logging around the request. Spring framework provides following
>   concrete implementation classes which can be used to log the incoming
>   request. These are:
>
> - [CommonsRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html)
> - [ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter.html)
>
> Spring Boot application can be configured by adding a bean definition to enable request
>   logging:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {
>
>     @Bean
>     public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
>         CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
>           = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
>         filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
>         filter.setIncludePayload(true);
>         filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
>         filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
>         filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
>         return filter;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Also, this logging filter requires the log level be set to DEBUG. In
>   `application.properties` put
>
> ```
> logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
> ```

To make the logging asynchronous, we may use [asynchronous appenders](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender). Unfortunately it does not support logging response payloads. :(

Comment: This is perfect fit to log request. But how about if we want to log response status code (200, 404, 500...)?

Comment: Yeah, this is only useful for logging requests. What about logging response payloads or response headers or response statuscodes etc? Did Spring forget to implement that? Should we implement that on our own is there a Spring class to do this?

Comment: this answer does not provide response logging, which is questioned.. not an actual answer..

Comment: Voting down. Incomplete answer. Doesn't mention how to log responses.

Comment: Extend ```CommonsRequestLoggingFilter```, and override ```doFilterInternal``` with ```super.doFilterInternal(...)``` will give access to response. Just log after super call.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 elements: A [LoggingFilter](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) and the [Async](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) support from Spring. For the first one, I would use a **CommonsRequestLoggingFilter** that already knows how to intercept the HTTP requests, create the configuration for that and the Async. You can do something like:

**First Enable Async Support**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig { ... }
```

Then Create the loggingFilter:

```
public class LoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {

@Override
protected void beforeRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final String message) {
    // DO something
    myAsyncMethodRequest(request, message)
}

@Override
protected void afterRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final String message) {
    // Do something
   myAsyncMethodResponse(request, message)
}

// -----------------------------------------
// Async Methods
// -----------------------------------------

   @Async
   protected void myAsyncMethodRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {

    // Do your thing
    // You can use message that has a raw message from the properties
   // defined in the logFilter() method. 
   // Also you can extract it from the HttpServletRequest using: 
   // IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());

   }

   @Async
   protected void myAsyncMethodResponse(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {

    // Do your thing
   }

}
```

Then create a custom logging configuration for the filter that you created:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LoggingConfiguration logFilter() {
        LoggingFilter filter
                = new LoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);

        return filter;
    }
}
```

To extract the data from the request you can use the `message` parameter or process the `HttpServletRequest`. Take as an example:

- https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/09/27/java-get-the-content-of-inputstream-from-httpservletrequest/
- [Get the POST request body from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100634/get-the-post-request-body-from-httpservletrequest)

Comment: How to get response body in CommonsRequestLoggingFilter ?

Comment: Well you just need to read the HttpServletRequest or also you can use `message` that it has the fields that you define in the annotated method with @Bean

Comment: Try something like this if you want to extract from the servlet and not from the message: `IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());`. Don't forget to catch or throw the Exception. After that you can process the message as you want. Also if you know that the content is JSON you can use Jackson or GSON to process it

Comment: I think this is the right way to define our logging filter class:  `public class LoggingFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter`.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your best option is to do the logging in an Async Method.

```
@Async
public void asyncMethodWithVoidReturnType() {
  System.out.println("Execute method asynchronously. "
    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Please refer to:

[Async](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

[How to Async](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)