# How to access the raw request payload before it is deserialized to a POJO by Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I want to access the raw payload (in my case Json body) before it gets deserialized into a POJO.

My controller has a method with a signature like the following.

```java
public ResponseEntity doSomething(@RequestBody @Validated Dto dto, Errors erros)
```

Now, I would like to just access the initial payload so that I can log it.

What I have tried so far is creating an interceptor in which get the `HttpServletRequest` object and get either `Reader` or `InputStream` and do the logging. It works perfect. But the issue is what happens afterwards. Since I have already accessed `Reader` or `InputStream` objects, it throws `IllegalStateException` saying `They have already been called`.

What I tried next was `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`. It solves the issue above but this time when I call the endpoint, it generates `Bad Request` with no response body. I think something's wrong with `ParameterMap` in this solution. Which is also pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250367/using-contentcachingrequestwrapper-causes-empty-parameters-map). Also the solution there doesn't work for me, the byte array seems empty.

So is there any way to log the raw payload before it is deserialized? I don't want to touch the controller, actually. To my mind, it would be better to do this through Interceptors. Thanks, beforehand.

**Update.** Thanks for directing me to correct resources. I used the following solution which worked perfectly. Adding `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` worked. But please note that `logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG` should be enabled.

```java
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://slackspace.de/articles/log-request-body-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Maybe also one of these:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/33744875/2886891
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48301764/2886891
https://stackoverflow.com/q/7952154/2886891