# Spring / Angular 7 POST method requestparameter is null

Tags: java, json, angular, spring, spring-boot

I would like to send datas (in json form) from frontend to backend using POST, but requestparameter is null.

Angular:

```
this.http.post('api/example', { mydata: JSON.stringify(data) },
 { "headers": { header: "text/html;charset=UTF-8" } }).subscribe(Response => console.log(Response);
});
```

JSON.stringify(data) looks like this:

```
[
  ["num1","num2","num3","num4","num5", "num6"],
  ["test6","test2","test1","test5","test4", "test3"]
]
```

This is just an example, the data will be dynamic, so sometimes I will have more or less columns and rows.

Spring backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/example", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void postExample(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String mydata = request.getParameter("mydata");
    System.out.println(mydata);
    ...
}
```

mydata is null, when I print out. I don't know why.
What I tried:

- change "text/html" to "application/json" and "application/*" and "text/plain" (and wanted to convert the text to json at backend, but still null parameter)

I would like to use "getParameter" instead of using @RequestBody annotation.

How can I get the json data from frontend and use it in backend?

Edit:
Originally I didn't want to use @RequestBody, but if I want to use it, how can I use it for getting these json arrays?

Comment: The problem is that `mydata` isn't a request parameter, but a request body. The easiest way is to use  `@RequestBody` but if you don't like it, you have to use one of the following approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100634/get-the-post-request-body-from-httpservletrequest

Comment: thank you. IF I would like to use @RequestBody, how can I use it, in this case? (because as you can see, I have multiple arrays)

Comment: You have to model your JSON schema as Java objects with Lists, as Marc says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595324/2470255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for using @RequestBody you'll need a Java data structure matching your JSON,
e.g. a nested array

```
@PostMapping(path="/api/example")
public void postExample(@RequestBody ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> body) {

    //....

}
```

Test case (from question above)

```
[
  ["num1","num2","num3","num4","num5", "num6"],
  ["test6","test2","test1","test5","test4", "test3"]
]
```

Comment: I tried this but I found a problem, when I print out `JSON.stringify(data)` in angular, then we can see the correct json (see above), but when I use `@RequestBody String mydata`, then I will get this:`{"mydata":"[[\"num1\",\"num2\",\"num3\",\"num4\",\"num5\",\"num6\"],[\"test6\",\"test2\",\"test1\",\"test5\",\"test4\",\"test3\"]]"}`

after that if I change String to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>, I will get `JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>> out of START_OBJECT token;` error.

Comment: If I am correct, then I should use simple String and parse everything by myself?

Comment: no, then use a pojo: `public class Dto {
    @JsonProperty("mydata")
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myData;
}`

Comment: I tried as you wrote + I had to change `this.http.post('api/example', { mydata: JSON.stringify(data) }` to `this.http.post('api/example', { mydata: data }` (removed  JSON.stringify) and now it is working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .getReader(), instead of the .getParameter() method, since you need to retrieve the body of the request not some parameter.