# CXF Rest Client - Pass HTTP Query Parameter by Default

Tags: java, rest, client, cxf

I am writing a Proxy based Rest client using Apache CXF and I would like to pass some of the query parameters without having to pass them in my "search" method in the proxy interface. I tried using @DefaultValue but with that you still have to define a method parameter which I have to pass the same exact value everywhere. Is there a way to tell CXF to pass a query parameter with the same value all the time? That way I can remove some of the unnecessary parameters from proxy methods.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{version}/{accountId}/search")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String search(@PathParam("version") String version,
                         @PathParam("accountId") String accountId,
                         @DefaultValue("")@QueryParam("q") String queryString,
                         @DefaultValue("")@QueryParam("category") String category,
                         @DefaultValue("1")@QueryParam("page") int page,
                         @DefaultValue("50")@QueryParam("limit") int limit,
                         @DefaultValue("all")@QueryParam("response_detail") String responseDetail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you try a different approach. create an object `SearchParameters` that will be just a plain pojo:

```
public class SearchParameters {
     private String version;
     private String accountId;
     // Other fields

     public static SearchParameters(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Here you use the getParameterMap of the `request` object to get
        // the query parameters. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847192/httpservletrequest-get-query-string-parameters-no-form-data

        // Everything that was not passed in the parameters
        // just init with default value as you wish.
     }

     // Getters and setters here
}
```

Now change the `search` definition to look like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{version}/{accountId}/search")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String search(@PathParam("version") String version,
                     @PathParam("accountId") String accountId,
                     @Context HttpServletRequest request);
```

In the `search` implementation just call the static builder from `SearchParameters` with `request` and there you have it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get a chance to try it yet. Priorities changed :) I will let you know when I get back to this. Thank you..