# HttpServletRequest.getParameterNames() - will this contain requestURL?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

Will this methodcall return the requestURL from the request? I have tried to read through the documentation, but haven't found the answer.

Comment: have a look at this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847192/httpservletrequest-get-query-string-parameters-no-form-data 
You may not be able to get the URL from httpservletrequest parameters, but you can get the queryString using request.getQueryString(), and I think its the same that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It return only parameters from the request (eg. from HTML form).

But you can use [`getRequestURL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL--).

Answer (score 1):

no, but `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()` will...