# Get URL parameter from request

Tags: eclipse-scout

how to get URL parameter from HttpServletRequest class, or on another way in FormBasedAccessController?

If I have url: http://example.com/&idcompany=13

I want to access idcompany variable in URL.

Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847192/httpservletrequest-get-query-string-parameters-no-form-data

Comment: Thanks, I did. But always get null for all avaliable methods for parameters

Comment: The query string in your URL is wrong. It must start with a '?'. The '&' is only used for additional parameters:
http://example.com/?idcompany=13&anotherid=24